# Is the purpose in slice-copying any more than to save a memory address?

Tags: python, slice

I've been reading a great article on Python [gotchas](http://www.toptal.com/python/top-10-mistakes-that-python-programmers-make). It discusses modifying lists while iterating over them and gives this example:

```
>>> odd = lambda x : bool(x % 2)
>>> numbers = [n for n in range(10)]
>>> numbers[:] = [n for n in numbers if not odd(n)]
>>> numbers
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```

On the third line the numbers variable is overwritten using the `[:]` slice notation so the value `id(numbers)` does not change.

I'm wondering is there any purpose in doing this other than saving an extra memory allocation and the associated clean-up? Would you tend to do this in day-to-day code or is it considered over-optimisation in normal circumstances?

Comment: "saving an extra memory allocation " erm... why do you think you are saving memory allocations? That line is still building a list of odd numbers, which *afterwards* get copied into `numbers` (which might cause other reallocations if the size is different) and finally is discarded. In other words doing: `numbers = [n for n in numbers if not odd(n)]` is *better*, efficiently speaking. Note that you could use a genexp instead of a list-comprehension to save allocations: `numbers[:] = (n for n in numbers if not odd(n))`. (Although this is modifying during the iteration, AFAIK safely)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any **other** references to the same list also are changed.

If you pass in a list to a function, that function has a local name bound to the same list object. Rebinding the name would not let you reflect the changes outside of the function, a slice assignment changes the original list instead:

```
>>> def rebinds(lst):
...     lst = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
... 
>>> def slice_assigns(lst):
...     lst[:] = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
... 
>>> somelist = [42, 81]
>>> rebinds(somelist)
>>> somelist
[42, 81]
>>> slice_assigns(somelist)
>>> somelist
['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
```

You could just return the new object and rebind the global, but the fact that you can change the list contents directly, making the changes visible to any code that already has a reference, can have advantages.

Comment: That's a nice example. Thank you